# Firebase is not defined. / No Firebase App

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

```
`var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: ****,
    authDomain: ****,
    databaseURL: "****",
    projectId: "****",
    storageBucket: "****",
    messagingSenderId: "*****",
    appId: "****",
    measurementId: "****"
};
`
```

```
`firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);`
```

in solo js.file.
Then i have in html file reference for this js file and i am trying to display data from database.
All the time i had error message: Firebase is not defined and it pointed to first of JS file. I manage to somehow change it to this error message:

```
rebaseNamespaceCore.ts:108 Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
    at p (firebaseNamespaceCore.ts:108:27)
    at Object.o [as database] (firebaseNamespaceCore.ts:207:53)
    at homelessFriends.html:101:36
```

Can you please tell me what i need to change in JS file to finally make it work? I found some solutions but that was for HTML but this yelling at me on JS.

My html scripts are:

top:

```
`  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src='https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-database.js'></script>
    <!-- materialize icons, css & js -->
    <link type="text/css" href="../css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link type="text/css" href="../css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/materialize.min.js"></script>`
```

bottom:

```
 <script src="../js/common.js"></script>
    <script>
        var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref("addHomelessFriendForm")
        firebaseRef.on("value", function (snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function (element) {
                document.querySelector("#root").innerHTML =
                    "<div>${element.val()}</div>"
            })
        })
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/configDB.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/firebase/7.14.1-0/firebase.js"></script>
```